# 404 error when calling REST API

Tags: c#, rest

I'm doing a little test for a friend who has provided me with details for a REST API (and therefore have needed to desensitise some info in the examples given).

They have provided me with the location of the REST API address location: http://databaseinfo.com and an example of a call on it: http://databaseinfo.com/getdata?somedata=5 which then returns some information. They have also said that some specific request headers need to be specified (for which I've just replaced this with a single Header = Value example).

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://databaseinfo.com/getdata?somedata=5");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Header", "Value");
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

When I run this code, the GetResponse() line throws a WebException 404 Not Found. I would assume this is because the end point doesn't exist but just wanted to check in case I was doing something silly with my code.

Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does the  request work from a browser or using Fiddler?

Comment: if you type http://databaseinfo.com/getdata?somedata=5 into your browser it takes you to a ad site... same with http://databaseinfo.com

Comment: @vc74 No it doesn't, however the details of the REST API says the specified request headers must be used to get a valid response. However, even with invalid request headers, I would assume I'd get some other error than a 404 error so this is why I think the API location doesn't work. Happy to send you the specific example in a private message but I can't see how I can do this.

Comment: @AmitWadhwa As I mentioned, I have changed the details to hide the specifics. databaseinfo.com is something I made up so it is not the actual info I'm using.

Comment: @PhilJ You can add those headers to your request using Fiddler or the latest browsers (I was more thinking about a proxy issue)

Comment: Seems like it was indeed a momentary outage on the Web Server I was contacting as it's now started to work correctly despite the code not changing. Thanks for the help.